# Creating a list of values that are not null

Tags: python, sqlite

Im trying to save three values from SQLite in a Python list. All values are from a different column but in the same row. If the value is null I dont want to add it to the list. This is the code I wrote:

```
    def create_list(self, chat):
    list = []
    for x in range(1, 3):
        column_name = "list" + str(x)
        value = c.execute("SELECT (?) FROM user WHERE (?) NOTNULL AND id = (?)", (column_name, column_name, chat)).fetchall()
        if value != None:
            list.append(value[0][0])
    print(list)
```

Instead of printing the SQLite values in a list it just prints: ['list1', 'list2', 'list3'] (If one of the values in the table is null it doesnt print that one. For example if the value in column liste3 is null it just prints ['list1', 'list2'])
How can I fix this so that it saves the actual SQLite values in the list?

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are solving in English? For example, this is a chat website, and you want to know if certain set of users have been chatting? Also what kind of data do you have in your tables? I'm sorry to say your choice of variable names is horrible and therefore your intentions with this code is completely unclear.

Comment: Its a chatbot where users can create lists together. Each user can be member to three lists. The names of the lists are saved in the columns list1, list2 and list3. This function should basically print out the names of the lists the user is a member in a python list in order for the bot to be able to output the names to the user. Sorry about the mess I hope its better now

Comment: You can't use DBAPI parameter substitution to paste SQL identifiers into a query. The first query you are executing is `SELECT ('list1') FROM user WHERE ('list1') NOTNULL AND id = ('whateverchatis')`. The parameters get inserted according to their Python type, in this case, as (quoted) strings.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Im a newb to python so can u tell me how I can convert 'column_name' to a datatype i can insert into a SQL statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, SQL: Set the columns read as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397150/python-sql-set-the-columns-read-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
SQLite package ignores NULL values by default after fetching the data. you need to put a condition that prints 'Empty' or something when it faces NULL values. something like:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("someDataBase.db")
db = conn.cursor()

db.execute('''
    SELECT name, email
    FROM person
    WHERE name = 'some dude'
''')

result = db.fetchone()  

if result is None: #if a value IS NULL
    print 'Empty'
else:
    var = result[0]
    print var
```